# WP REST API ERROR 401 While trying to fetch image from wp:featuredmedia

Tags: javascript, wordpress, api, rest

I'm trying to fetch featured image from my published post but it seems impossible! I get
an error :( that's the code:

```
function fetchSlideShow(){
let endpoint = "http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/Vinyls?_embed";
fetch(endpoint)
.then(e => e.json())
.then(showSlideShow);
}

function showSlideShow(data){
console.log(data);
data.forEach(showSingleSlide);   
showSlides();
}

function showSingleSlide(aSlide) {
let template = document.querySelector(".slide_template").content;
let clone = template.cloneNode(true);
console.log(aSlide);  
clone.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", aSlide._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"] 
[0].media_details.source_url);

let SlideList = document.querySelector("#SlideList");
SlideList.appendChild(clone);
}
```

While going to the array I see error 401 :( and moreover: Cannot read property 'source_url' of undefined" I don't know what I'm doing wrong .. any insights?
[HERE ARE THE ERRORS -> 401 ON CONSOLE + PROBLEM WITH URL.:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPWMj.png)

Answer (score 2):

Please try changing your url in the endpoint variable:

```
let endpoint = "http://loreleiheckmann.com/wordpress/wordpress/wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&_embed=wp:featuredmedia
```

If you need more data you can add them with a comma:

```
wp-json/wp/v2/posts?per_page=20&_embed=wp:term,wp:featuredmedia
```

Post per page is optional, but I would prefer having that set.

And you should write what image size you need. That way rest api will give you the right source url:

```
_embedded['wp:featuredmedia']['0'].media_details.sizes.medium_large.source_url
```

I think it would also be better practice if you use an ssl certificate, there are free by "Let's encrypt".

**EDIT:**

Your screenshot shows the rest api message:

```
wp:featuredmedia: Array(1)
    0:
    code: "rest_forbidden"
    data: {status: 401}
    message: "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that."
```

So the 401 status code means: unauthorised

Seems like you are not allowed to access the data via rest api.

There could be multiple reasons for that:

- The image is attached to an unpublished post. The post may have the status "private" or "draft", and therefore is not public available.
- Your post (and attached image) is not available for not logged in users. If there is a restriction to view your code, this also applies to rest api.
- Maybe you are using some kind of membership plugin that restricts the wp rest-api. Try deactivating all plugins if one of them affects the behaviour.
- You have added some custom code to restrict access rest api access.

If nothing works for you, you should look into your database and check the medias post_status.

I think it is working fine, but you do not have access to view the posts data. This is what the 401 error indicates.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. My code: function showSingleSlide(aSlide) {
 
    let template = document.querySelector(".slide_template").content;
    let clone = template.cloneNode(true);
    console.log(aSlide);  
    clone.querySelector("img").setAttribute("src", aSlide._embedded["wp:featuredmedia"][0].media_details.source_url);
 console.log ("checked")
 
    
    let SlideList = document.querySelector("#SlideList");
    SlideList.appendChild(clone);
 } and still I get an error in console "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined" I really don't understand anymore.

Comment: I edited my answer. Maybe everything is good now, but you just don't have access to the data.

Comment: H :) In the end, I added image in WP by custom post type not featured media - I wasn't able to fetch it. Afterward I added a code -> b.querySelector(".img").setAttribute("src", a.acf.image.url); so it works:) thanks for help :)

Comment: It would be nice, if you post your own solution and accept it as the answer. This way users finding this post might have an working solution when facing the same problem. You can also appreciate answers with giving them an upvote. Thank you and I'm glad you solved your issue.

Answer (score 1):

To whom it may concern - In the end, I added image in WP by custom post type ( I gave up wp:featured media - I wasn't able to fetch it.) Afterward I added a code to JS -> b.querySelector(".img").setAttribute("src", a.acf.image.url); so it works:)